# ASP.NET An attribute argument must be a constant expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

In my ASP.net project i'm using the [Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.ASPX) to only allow a user that is member of the given group. To make this a bit more easy for a future owner of the website i'm making the role adjustable. I try to do the following:

```
SettingsController set = new SettingsController();

private string Roles()
{
    return set.settingsGroup;
}

[Authorize(Roles = Roles())]
....
```

Now `set.settingsGroup` returns a string that is parsed from a XML file.
But when i try to set it on the Authorize i get the error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or
>   property

I don't fully understand the error, so i'm asking you guys and girls for help.

So don't be shy.

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*UPDATE****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

So with some help i now understand what i have to do.
And as a solution i made de function roles static, and created a new instance of SettingsController.

```
private static string Roles()
{
    SettingsController set = new SettingsController();
    set.parseXML();
    return set.settingsGroup;
}
```

But now when i call Roles() in the Authorize is get an new error that is even longer:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

So if i try to read this error is seems that a give an attribute or parameter with the Roles() function. And that is not of the correct type. But i don't give any parameters so?

Comment: make Roles() function static.

private static string Roles() {}

Answer (score 2):

you are calling a non static property from a static method. You will need to either make the property static, or create an instance of set within the Roles function

Comment: This answer helped me with the first part

Comment: set.settingsGroup returns a string which isn't constant. You need to declare a constant string, set set.settingsGroup to it, and return that string. public const string settingsGroup = set.settingsGroup; return settingsGroup;